# Keras model the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I have  the problem with keras model. 
I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 165757 arrays: [array([[0],
   [1]]), array([[2],
   [3]]), array([[4],
   [5]]), array([[6],
   [7]]), array([[8],
   [9]]), array([[10],
   [11]]), array([[12],
   [13]]), array([[14],
```

...

That accure in the training part :

```
model.fit (X_train, y_train,
       batch_size=64,
       epochs=7,
       validation_data=(X_dev, y_dev),
       verbose=1)
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=64)
print("Accuracy is: %.2f%%" %(scores[1] * 100))
```

The problem is in X_train. As data I have pairs of words, that could be related to each other or not. The words I represented as ids:

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 5],
 [4, 6],
 [7, 8]]
```

The model according to the error want the data to be one list. The problem is, that I need to pass pairs. Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Comment: X_train should be a single numpy array of shape `(165757, 2)` instead of a list of 165757 individual arrays. Can you try passing `np.array(X_train)` instead?

Comment: it worked, but after 3 epochs the same error.... here is a link to the whole code https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online#&togetherjs=1oQB1To2ND